# Who was the first Alien in The Worlds End?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-worlds-end

In The Worlds End, the 5 main characters' town gets taken over by aliens who convert the inhabitants into what they call "blanks". Later on, after reaching the last pub they find themselves talking to the entity who is apparently the "head alien", who tells them that they invaded the world to provide a better life for everyone etc.

The question is, who was this first alien that came to Earth who then turned everyone else into the "blanks" - it had to start from one in order to propagate to everyone else?

Comment: I don't think that it is shown in the movie.

Answer (score 3):

### The Network

Your question conflates the aliens with the blanks, but they are two different things. The Network, voiced by Bill Nighy, is the alien entity who speaks to the main characters in the climactic scene. He (and possibly others like him) is the one who landed in 1990. It is implied that although we do not see him, he is the one who can transfer their consciousnesses into the blanks of their younger selves. He is an alien, not a blank.

Which blank was created *first* and which human was converted first is not specified. Mr. Shepherd, Gary's teacher, appears to take a kind of leadership role among the blanks, so maybe he was the first, but that's just speculation.